# Following this domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

I have some questions on a few points which were not very clear during [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IOTI9ViExg) at **3:31:30** where the professor starts discussing a new example function and its domain.

> 1. I understand how the professor turned around the inequality by
>    multiplying both sides by -1, however I do not understand why he took
>    this step?
> 2. I do not understand how the numberline was plotted, and why some
>    sections have a + or - above it. I would not even know how to read it for the purposes of the exercise.
> 3. I see there is a range shown with the interval [-2, 2] which means
>    all numbers -2,-1,0,1,2 can be used as a variable for the g(x)
>    function. However, I have tested values outside the that range which
>    appear valid... perhaps I did not input them correctly?
> 4. Why would you want (x-2)(x+2) to be less than or equal to zero, when he previously said negative numbers cannot be used in the square root as we are using real numbers?

I hope someone can walk me through, it could be something as simple as me getting the negative numbers confused or something else that is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand how the professor turned around the inequality by multiplying both sides by -1, however I do not understand why he took this step?

Strictly speaking it's not necessary. You could not do that, and have

$$4-x^2 = (2-x)(2+x) \ge 0$$

and work it similarly, to get similar results.

> I do not understand how the numberline was plotted, and why some sections have a + or - above it. I would not even know how to read it for the purposes of the exercise.

The idea is that we want to know when $x^2 - 4$ is positive or negative. It is positive when $x > 2$ or $x<-2$, and it is negative when $x \in [-2,2]$.

This is particularly important of a realization because we want the domain of the function $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ (or $\sqrt{x^2-4}$). For this, we need to know when $4-x^2 \ge 0$, or, equivalently, $x^2 - 4 \le 0$. The reason being that if $4-x^2 < 0$ (or $x^2 - 4 > 0$) then we're taking the square root of a negative number -- something we don't want!

> I see there is a range shown with the interval [-2, 2] which means all numbers -2,-1,0,1,2 can be used as a variable for the g(x) function. However, I have tested values outside the that range which appear valid... perhaps I did not input them correctly?

You must have, yes. Bear in mind that we want $4-x^2 \ge 0$, or $x^2 - 4 \le 0$. If you end up taking the square root of a negative when you plug in something for $x$ into $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ (or $\sqrt{x^2 - 4}$), then that $x$ is not in the domain.

You might still get an answer, sure, but it would be what we call a complex number. For now, the professor seems to be ignoring this case, since it's usually not particularly relevant. So whenever we find the square root of a negative in precalculus we usually brush that aside as being "undesirable for the time being" -- we focus on real numbers instead.

> Why would you want (x-2)(x+2) to be less than or equal to zero, when he previously said negative numbers cannot be used in the square root as we are using real numbers?

Multiplying by $-1$ reversed the inequality. That is,

$$a \le b \iff -a \ge -b$$

If you didn't multiply by $-1$, then you would have $(2-x)(2+x) \ge 0$ instead.

Comment: You have been so helpful! For the sake of any further questions assume I did multiply both sides by -1 and also rearranged the question to be g(x) = sqrt( (x)^2 -4) which I think follows BODMAS rules properly?
A) You said to find out when it is positive and negative, but what about when it is zero which I thought was a neutral number?
B) When the professor wrote the graph why did he know it was -2 and 2 which had to be plotted, may I assume it is because of the brackets above?